# variable gets reset when entering if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I have code where I loop through all pixels of an image, this includes 2 for loops:

```
for (x = 1; x < img.width; x++) {
    visited[x] = new Array();
    for (y = 1; y < img.height; y++) {
        visited[x][y] = false;
        count = deepCount(img, x, y, visited, 0);
        if (count > spotSize) {
            spotX = x;
            spotY = y;
            spotSize = count;
        }
    }
}
```

This code all words, up until the `if` statement. When I try to get variable `x` and `y` and put their values in to new variables, they give the value of `1`. However, if I `console.log` the values before the if statement, they give another number.

It seems like the variables get reset to the value given to them in the for loop, because when I change their starting value to `"0"`, `x` and `y` both return `0`, thus my question is:

How is it possible that these variables can be reset to their initial value when entering an if statement?

Comment: `x` and `y` are declared globally. Are they overwritten in `deepCount`?

Comment: Can you share the exact (relevant) code rather than a description? It's just not possible that `x` and `y` change their values right at `count > spotSize`.

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve]. The process of creating one is likely to identify the problem for you.

Comment: @Mouser They're not overwritten in deep count

Comment: don't declare x and y globally and ensure deepCount doesn't change them

Comment: How can we tell if `deepCount()` isn't overwriting the vars if it's not posted? Is `deepCount()` a new method we're not aware of?

Comment: In the case that the function `deepCount` returns its maximum value for `x=1` and `y=1` (or `0` respectively), then you would only enter the `if` body once, hence never get other values than `1` or `0` inside the `if` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested a similar code, with 2 FOR statements. Works fine, X and Y change value as expected.

```js
function matrix() {

var mx = "";  
var xrand = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 + 2 );
var yrand = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 + 2 );  

for (x = 1; x < xrand; x++) {
    for ( y = 1; y < yrand; y++) {
        mx += "[" + x + "," + y + "]";
    }
    mx += "\n";
}
console.log(mx);
}

matrix()
```

Can you make sure that:
1. img.width and img.height actually produce value
2. visited function does not alter X, Y value
3. test using other values instead of X or Y
4. remove everything except the FOR and IF statements, but replace the condition inside IF with something else like if (true) just to test things out

I'd say that somewhere along the path X and Y are set to a given value by any of the functions involved in that code.